# Non-persistent XSS - Meaning of '== in the URL

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, iis-7, xss

I'm trying to understand non-persistent XSS attack. I learnt that one of the non-persistent XSS form is adding executable  along with js in the URL like below

```
http://www.myxsssite.com/default.aspx?requesturl=<script>alert(hello)</script>
```

I'm on IIS and if I try the above example, IIS itself throws-up exception saying "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (<)."

But when I try the below URL I get to see an alert dialog with whatever I've added in that

```
http://www.myxsssite.com/default.aspx?requesturl=docs/help-files/main.htm'==alert(hello)=='
```

The second case occurs when an unauthenticated user tries to access the help files directly wherein the above URL gets constructed followed by redirecting to Login page. Once logged in the requesturl param will be used to redirect back to where the user started.

If the same process is replayed with a tab already having valid session it won't show the alert dialog.

The question I've here is what is the significance of '== ==', without which I don't see alert dialog

---

**EDIT:**

While redirecting to Login page this is the Response body

```
<html><head><script>window.top.location='http://www.myxsssite.com/default.aspx?requesturl=docs/help-files/main.htm'==alert(hello)=='';</script></head><body></body></html>
```

**The key thing I've noticed is, If I take the URL from the response and paste it in the Browser it does not shows the alert dialog.**

Now it boils down to why the alert in the URL gets fired when location is set through Javascript and why not when copied directly into the browser.

Comment: I would assume that it's closing the string, comparing it to "alert(hello)", then reopening the string, if that helps

Comment: It depends on what default.aspx is doing with the requesturl parameter.  It must be rendering it into the returned HTML somehow.

Comment: I've additional information. See if that gives better understanding of the scenario